# Flutter: ListView with StreamBuilder Janky on Scroll Up

Tags: flutter, firebase, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a long list of posts that is using `ListView.builder` with a `StreamBuilder` inside of the list (to get users docs). The list scrolls perfectly while scrolling *down*. However, when scrolling up, it is very janky and typically scrolls all the way back to the top of the list. I have read several threads that also report this as an issue, but nothing seems to solve the problem. It does appear to be caused by the loading widget indicator and the `StreamBuilder` inside of the `ListView` while rebuilding the post on the scroll up after being disposed of on the scroll down, but if I set the height the same, it stops from scroll up (height of the posts is 400).

Is there anyway to 'rebuild' the widgets scrolling up like it does scrolling down? This seems like a major issue with Flutter ListView's. Here is some code on the `ListView` and the nested `StreamBuilder`.

```
//first query to get posts docs
StreamBuilder<List<PostsRecord>>(
                stream: queryPostsRecord(
                  queryBuilder: (postsRecord) =>
                      postsRecord.orderBy('created_time', descending: true),
                  limit: 200,
                ),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Color,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  List<PostsRecord> listViewPostsRecordList = snapshot.data;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: listViewPostsRecordList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, listViewIndex) {
                      final listViewPostsRecord =
                          listViewPostsRecordList[listViewIndex];
                      return Visibility(
                        visible: !(vis.check)) ??
                            true,
//this is the StreamBuilder to get the users docs
                        child: StreamBuilder<UsersRecord>(
                          stream:
                              UsersRecord.getDocument(listViewPostsRecord.user),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return Center(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 40,
//I tried setting this to 400 (size of media in post) but it prevented from scrolling up
                                  height: 40,
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: Color,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            final containerUsersRecord = snapshot.data;
                            return Posts()
//feed posts vary in height, but the media within the posts is 400 pixels
```

Here is a quick screen recording showing the issue:

https://youtube.com/shorts/ADz1hUtkMTQ?feature=share

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Is there a way to rebuild widgets on the scroll up just like it does scrolling down? Seems like a major issue for flutter apps.

UPDATE

I added `print(listViewIndex);` to see which index was being built. I scrolled slowly to the 11th post and everything built fine. Then just scrolled up a little and it built every child above in rapid succession. How do you stop this?

```
flutter: 2
flutter: 3
flutter: 4
flutter: 5
flutter: 6
flutter: 7
flutter: 8
flutter: 9
flutter: 10
flutter: 11
//stop scroll and down and barely scrolled up
flutter: 7
flutter: 6
flutter: 5
flutter: 4
flutter: 3
flutter: 2
flutter: 1
flutter: 0
```

Comment: did you make sure that `itemBuilder` is not called redundantly when scrolling up?

Comment: How do you do that? Sorry, still pretty new to Flutter.

Comment: `print(listViewIndex)` and check how often it is called when scrolling up and down

Comment: Thanks for that. Here is the output `flutter: 3
flutter: 4
flutter: 5
flutter: 6
flutter: 7
flutter: 8
flutter: 9
flutter: 7
flutter: 6
flutter: 5
flutter: 4
flutter: 3
flutter: 2
flutter: 1
flutter: 0`
I scrolled down to index=9 and then barely scrolled up and it jumped to the top.

Comment: so as you can see there is no difference between scrolling up and down - no index is repeated (for example you don't see 7,7,7,6,6,6,5,5,5,4,4,4,4 etc) - most likely `UsersRecord.getDocument(listViewPostsRecord.user)` is broken or something

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help. The Stream is working perfectly fine on the scroll down, so it is working when the widget is originally built. But for some reason after the widgets are disposed and then re-enter the viewport, it is causing the issue.

Comment: yes but the same applies when you scroll down, for example scroll to index 20, then scroll up and again scroll down - the stream for item 20 will be created again

Comment: @pskink is there a way to stop that from happening? It just doesn't make sense that a disposed widget behaves differently when it is rebuilt compared to when it is first built in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scrolling up problem with a ListView.Builder as part of an Autocomplete Widget. I found that the ensureVisible call somehow conflicted with scrolling up, so I commented it out. Because it is needed when you want to use the up and down keys of a keyboard and I don't need that in my app. Hope this helps you narrow down your bug.

```
if (highlight) {
  SchedulerBinding.instance
      .addPostFrameCallback((Duration timeStamp) {
    Scrollable.ensureVisible(context, alignment: 0.5);
  });
}
```